# Royalslider - position navigation outside of slider

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

My site here: http://s168249.gridserver.com/ uses two Royal Slider plugins. The bottom one is the one I'm trying to reconfigure. I need to place the navigation arrows outside of the slider which is 960px wide. The container is set to overflow: hidden to prevent the extra slides from showing. Is there a way to manipulate the navigation via css or will I have to make my own navigation outside of the plugin and attach all the necessary classes and ids?

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the code of the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

edit css to:

```
Line 62
.rsVisibleNearbyWrap {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

Line 71
.rsVisibleNearbyWrap .rsOverflow {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

Line 54
.rsDefaultInv.rsHor .rsArrowLeft {
    left: -54px;
    top: 0;
}

Line 55
.rsDefaultInv.rsHor .rsArrowRight {
    right: -15px;
    top: 0;
}
```